# Why does eglCreatePbufferSurface give EGL_NO_SURFACE when DISPLAY environment variable is set?

Tags: c++, linux, shell, opengl, egl

I have ran into a very strange issue. I am using Ubuntu 20.04. The following minimal example is supposed to set up an EGL context (for later OpenGL rendering).

```
#include <EGL/egl.h>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <sstream>

#define ASSERT( expression ) \
    if( !( expression ) ) \
    { \
        std::stringstream details; \
        details \
            << "Failed expression: " << #expression << std::endl \
            << "File: " << __FILE__ << std::endl \
            << "Line: " << __LINE__; \
        throw std::runtime_error( details.str() ); \
    }

static const EGLint CONFIG_ATTRIBS[] =
{
    EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_PBUFFER_BIT,
    EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
    EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
    EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
    EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 8,
    EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_BIT,
    EGL_NONE
};

static const EGLint PBUFFER_ATTRIBS[] =
{
    EGL_WIDTH, 8,
    EGL_HEIGHT, 8,
    EGL_NONE
};

int main()
{
    EGLDisplay eglDpy;
    EGLSurface eglSurf;
    EGLContext eglCtx;
    
    eglDpy = eglGetDisplay( EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY );
    EGLint major, minor;
    eglInitialize( eglDpy, &major, &minor );
    
    eglBindAPI( EGL_OPENGL_API );

    EGLint numConfigs;
    EGLConfig eglCfg;

    auto cfgResult = eglChooseConfig( eglDpy, CONFIG_ATTRIBS, &eglCfg, 1, &numConfigs );
    ASSERT( cfgResult == EGL_TRUE );

    eglSurf = eglCreatePbufferSurface( eglDpy, eglCfg, PBUFFER_ATTRIBS );
    ASSERT( eglSurf != EGL_NO_SURFACE ); // <-- this assertion fails

    eglCtx  = eglCreateContext( eglDpy, eglCfg, EGL_NO_CONTEXT, NULL );
    ASSERT( eglCtx != EGL_NO_CONTEXT );
}
```

I use the command line

```
c++ egltest.cpp -lGL -lEGL -o egltest
```

...for compilation and linking.

When I am on the desktop and run `./egltest` afterwards, the following error occurs:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Failed expression: eglSurf != EGL_NO_SURFACE
File: egltest.cpp
Line: 53
```

However, it *works* if I use `unset DISPLAY && ./egltest` for running. So a workaround would be to use `unsetenv( "DISPLAY" );` in the first line of my `main` function (tested and yes it works too). But, and this is a huge but, ***why* is it necessary to unset `DISPLAY`?**

Comment: Make sure to check that `eglChooseConfig()` returns something greater than zero for `numConfigs` before attempting the `eglCreatePbufferSurface()`.

Comment: @genpfault The return value of `eglChooseConfig` always is `1`, no metter whether I unset `DISPLAY` or not. According to the [docs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/EGL/sdk/docs/man/html/eglChooseConfig.xhtml), however, return value of `1` indicates success and `0` indices failure, so `eglChooseConfig` is fine. I have updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Not the actual return value, the `num_config` output argument.  It can return success but still set `num_config` to zero (and not update `configs`) if no configs match `attrib_list`.

Comment: @genpfault You were right, `num_config` is set to zero if `DISPLAY` environment variable is set. It is set to `1` otherwise. But why?

Comment: Might try cross-checking the attributes you're trying to use with the per-`EGLDisplay` attribute dump provided by `eglinfo` (from `mesa-utils-extra` in Debian).

Comment: On my system `eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY)` looks to be using the GBM platform which has no pbuffer configs.  Forcing X11 usage via `eglGetPlatformDisplay(EGL_PLATFORM_X11_KHR, EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY, nullptr)` shows some pbuffer configs, matching `eglinfo`.  (Note that `EGL_PLATFORM_X11_KHR` is an extension enum and the corresponding extension ([`KHR_platform_x11`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/EGL/extensions/KHR/EGL_KHR_platform_x11.txt)) should be checked for support at runtime before using it)